# Scala constructor JWTVerifier in class JWTVerifier cannot be accessed in object X

Tags: scala, constructor

I realize some other people have asked similar questions before, but from what I can tell, they are using classes with private constructors. The problem I am dealing with is not being able to create a JWTVerifier instance (using a public constructor) that I would like to use to verify some jwt token. Here is the snippet of my code where I try to initialize it:

```
  NettyServerBuilder

  ...

  .intercept(new JWTServerInterceptor(
    "ajsdklfsadf",
    new JWTVerifier("ajsdklfsadf"),
    logger))
  .build()
```

The JWTServerInterceptor constructor looks like the following:

```
  class JWTServerInterceptor(
    val secret: String,
    val verifier: JWTVerifier,
    val logger: Logger)
      extends ServerInterceptor
```

Am I missing out on anything? The error I am getting is:

```
error: constructor JWTVerifier in class JWTVerifier cannot be accessed in object
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The issue is with the `JWTVerifier` class, how is it defined?

Comment: I am importing it using "import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier"

Comment: @GaëlJ third definition [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.auth0/java-jwt/2.2.2/com/auth0/jwt/JWTVerifier.html#JWTVerifier-java.lang.String-) allows using a string as an argument to the constructor